# Binding RadGrid on button click?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have an aspx page that initially shows a treeview. When a child node on the tree is pressed, i want a RadGrid on the page to be populated. I set the datasource and do a databind() call but it doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried using needDataSource but it has the same problem. Here's my code:

```
namespace MCMwebapp{ public partial class frmLookupTables : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 

    int CurrentDemog;
    bool LookupDataLoaded;
    bool isOPS = false;
    string selectedNode;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }

    }



    protected void LookupsTree_NodeClick(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {

        RadTreeNode currNode = e.Node;
        if (currNode.Nodes.Count == 0) {
            if (currNode.ParentNode.Text != "Treatments" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currNode.Text))
            {
                selectedNode = currNode.Text;
                Session["selectedNode"] = selectedNode;
                loadLookupGrid();

            }

        }

    }


    protected void loadLookupGrid()
    {
        using (ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient myService = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient())
        {
            if (Session["selectedNode"] != null)
            {
                LookupGrid.DataSource = myService.getTable();
                LookupGrid.Databind();

            }
        }


}
```

}

My aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="frmLookupTables.aspx.cs" Inherits="MCMwebapp.frmLookupTables" %>
```

```
<asp:Label ID="LookupLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>


  <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="LookupGrid">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="LookupGrid" LoadingPanelID="TablePanel"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

 <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="TreePanel" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="NotSet" style="background-color:#808080; float:left" Width="40%">


     <telerik:RadTreeView ID="LookupsTree" runat="server" OnClientNodeClicked="ClientNodeClicked" OnNodeClick="LookupsTree_NodeClick">

    </telerik:RadTreeView>

</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>



 <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="TablePanel" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right"
    style="background-color:#E92326; float:right" Width="40%" >


     <telerik:RadGrid ID="LookupGrid" runat="server" BackColor="Gray"
         BorderColor="#404040" BorderStyle="Solid" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None"
         Skin="MetroTouch">

         <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
         </FilterMenu>
     </telerik:RadGrid>




 </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function ClientNodeClicked(sender, eventArgs) {
       var node = eventArgs.get_node();
       node.toggle();
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
  <AjaxSettings>
      <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="LookupGrid">
          <UpdatedControls>
              <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="LookupGrid" LoadingPanelID="TablePanel"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
          </UpdatedControls>
      </telerik:AjaxSetting>
  </AjaxSettings>
```

Into:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
  <AjaxSettings>
      <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="LookupsTree">
          <UpdatedControls>
              <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="LookupGrid" LoadingPanelID="TablePanel"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
          </UpdatedControls>
      </telerik:AjaxSetting>         
      <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="LookupGrid">
          <UpdatedControls>
              <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="LookupGrid" LoadingPanelID="TablePanel"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
          </UpdatedControls>
      </telerik:AjaxSetting>
  </AjaxSettings>
```

The problem is your AJAX is enabled, and your `RadTreeView` does not have the permission to update the `RadGrid` in AJAX.

When using the `RadAjaxManager`, you can remove the embracing `RadAjaxPanels`.

Also, I don't think the `Session` can be set on an Ajax PostBack, not sure though. There is no need to put it inside the `Session`, as you can pass it as a parameter through your function - `loadLookupGrid(selectedNode);`.

Comment: hmm still not showing. If I put a break point right after the databind() it shows the the LookupTable is populated, the grid has its "datasource" property set and if I expand the dataSource property it shows that it has columns, but the columns on the grid are zero..

Comment: Did you remove the Session and did you pass your selectedNode as a parameter to loadLookupGrid? And can I see what 'ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient()', this class does do?

Comment: Service reference works correctly. Its just a simpple query to a db and fills a data table. Yes, I removed the session variable and the conditional statement for testing.

Comment: I think your right that has something to do with the ajax. I just made a test project and was able to populate the grid on a radButton click.

Comment: Havent got it working yet, but reverse engineering it right now. So hopefully a matter of time. I noticed that radajaxloadpanels cause it not to bind() but regular radAjax Panels do, at least for my test project.